# Design Patterns and Scala

Tags: design-patterns, scala

I'm writing this question to maintain a register of design patterns associated with Scala, standards patterns or only from this language.

**Associated questions:**

- [Scala Catalog of functional Design Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205721/scala-catalog-of-functional-design-patterns)
- [Design patterns for static type checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566708/design-patterns-for-static-type-checking)

Thanks to all who contribute

Comment: Realizing it's too late, but this really should be community wiki

Comment: @Dave Agreed, I don't think this is a SO-legal question. But, I'm very interested in seeing the answers and I hope it continues!

Comment: You might also want to link to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566708/design-patterns-for-static-type-checking).

Comment: You may take a look at http://pavelfatin.com/design-patterns-in-scala/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list like this has been collated already. See https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SYGN/Design+Patterns

Answer (score 7):

Let's start with the **"Singleton pattern"**:

```
object SomeSingleton //That's it
```

---

I would additionally propose the **"Using-functions-of-higher-order pattern"**.
Instead of e. g. iterating through a collection by yourself you supply functions to the methods the classes provide.

In Scala you basically say what you intend to do:

```
//declare some example class
case class Person(name: String, age: Int) 

//create some example persons
val persons = List(Person("Joe", 42), Person("Jane", 30), Person("Alice", 14), Person("Bob", 12))

//"Are there any persons in this List, which are older than 18?"
persons.exists(_.age > 18)
// => Boolean = true

//"Is every person's name longer than 4 characters?"
persons.forall(_.name.length > 4)
// => Boolean = false

//"I need a List of only the adult persons!"
persons.filter(_.age >= 18)
// => List[Person] = List(Person(Joe,42), Person(Jane,30))

//"Actually I need both, a list with the adults and a list of the minors!"
persons.partition(_.age >= 18)
// => (List[Person], List[Person]) = (List(Person(Joe,42), Person(Jane,30)),List(Person(Alice,14), Person(Bob,12)))

//"A List with the names, please!"
persons.map(_.name)
// => List[String] = List(Joe, Jane, Alice, Bob)    

//"I would like to know how old all persons are all together!"
persons.foldLeft(0)(_ + _.age)
// => Int = 98
```

Doing this in Java would have meant touching the elements of a collection yourself and mix your application logic with flow control code.

[More information](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html) about the Collection classes.

---

This nice [EPFL paper](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~imaier/pub/DeprecatingObserversTR2010.pdf) about **Deprecating the Observer Pattern** might be of interest, too.

---

**[Typeclasses](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4039)** are one approach to structure common features of classes where inheritance doesn't really fit.

Comment: It's sad that the "level" or common programming language is such that these ... constructs ... must be brought out and called "design patterns" (as if they should warrant any additional burden :-)

Comment: "Using-functions-of-higher-order pattern" is GoF's Strategy

Comment: To make singletons more testable it is always better to leave partial if not full implementation in a trait.
//code

trait SomeSingleton{
def doSomething1{}
lazy val val1
}

object SomeSingleton extends SomeSingleton

Answer (score 1):

This is a list of materials related to design patterns using Scala language:

- [DI in Scala: Cake Pattern pros & cons](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/di_in_scala_cake_pattern_pros_and_cons.html)
- [Design Patterns in Scala](http://memuser.blogspot.com/2008/03/design-patterns-in-scala.html)
- [Scala's Stackable Trait Pattern](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html)
- [Specification pattern](http://ouertani.com/2010/11/specification-pattern-by-scala/)
- Video - [Design Patterns in Scala](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/video_design_patterns_in_scala.html)

Answer (score -5):

```
//Triangle pattern using Scala:
object Exercise {
  def main(args:Array [String]){
    var n = 6
   for (i<-1 to 6){

     for (j<-i to (2*n-2))
     {
       print(" ")       
     }
     for(j<- 0 to i-1)
     {
     print(" *")
   }
     println(" ")
   }


  }
}
```

Output:
           * 
          * * 
         * * * 
        * * * * 
       * * * * * 
      * * * * * *

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with design patterns and is unrelated to the question.

Comment: Design Patterns are typical solutions to commonly occurring problems in software design. This answer is unrelated.